# How to remove a child from from a node using jdom in java?

Tags: java, xml, parent-child, jdom

I have a xml structure as follows:

```
<rurl modify="0" children="yes" index="8" name="R-URL">
    <status>enabled</status>
    <rurl-link priority="3">http</rurl-link>
    <rurl-link priority="5">http://localhost:80</rurl-link>
    <rurl-link priority="4">abc</rurl-link>
    <rurl-link priority="3">b</rurl-link>
    <rurl-link priority="2">a</rurl-link>
    <rurl-link priority="1">newlinkkkkkkk</rurl-link>
</rurl>
```

Now, I want to remove a child node, where text is equal to http. currently I am using this code:

```
while(subchilditr.hasNext()){
    Element subchild = (Element)subchilditr.next();
    if (subchild.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
        message = subchild.getText();
        update = "Success";
        subchild.removeAttribute("priority");
        subchild.removeContent();
    }
```

But it is not completely removing the sub element from xml file. It leaves me with

```
<rurl-link/>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do this:

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

while (subchilditr.hasNext()) {
    Element subchild = (Element) subchilditr.next();
    if (subchild.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
        elements.add(subchild);
    }
}

for (Element element : elements) {
    element.getParent().removeContent(element);
}
```

If you try to remove an element inside of the loop you'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I tried it..It was successful for the first time..but after that..I started getting null pointer exception. Any idea?!

Comment: Well..i got it..I just cleared all the elements arraylist after the for loop. And it solved my problem. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the parent element `rurl` you can remove its children using the method [removeChild](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#removeChild%28java.lang.String%29) or [removeChildren](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#removeChildren%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I dont want to remove all the rurl-link childs..I just want the the a single node to be deleted if it matches my condition.

Comment: @mad_programmer: `element.getParent().removeContent(child)` will do the job. See the class [org.jdom.Parent](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Parent.html) for more information.

Comment: this removes all the <rurl-link/> element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeChild()`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#removeChild(org.w3c.dom.Node)